# Поиск-замена, требуется "отловить" числа в диапазоне. Регэкспом можно?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Озадачился и встал в тупик. Есть числа в диапазоне от 0 до 300, нужно отловить от 15 до 213 включительно. Можно ли регэкспом?

Comment: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Comment: А рассматривается только один шаг?
Нельзя вытаскивать все числа, приводить их к int и потом сравнивать с диапазоном?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант:

```
(1[5-9]|[2-9]\d|1\d\d|20\d|21[0-3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Эм.. Можно. Но зачем?

```
Числа 0 to 14:
^0*(\d{1,1}|(([0-0]\d{1})|(1(([0-3]\d{0})|(4)))))$

Числа 0 to 213
^0*(\d{1,2}|(([0-1]\d{2})|(2(([0-0]\d{1})|(1(([0-2]\d{0})|(3)))))))$

Итог: числа 15 to 213
(?!(^0*(\d{1,1}|(([0-0]\d{1})|(1(([0-3]\d{0})|(4)))))$))(^0*(\d{1,2}|(([0-1]\d{2})|(2(([0-0]\d{1})|(1(([0-2]\d{0})|(3)))))))$)
```

Понимаю, что вообще не оптимально, но уж такой генератор регулярок я написал несколько лет назад.